# Jquery selector is not returning jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning Jquery.

I have following html code.

```
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h1>Heading 2</h1>
  <h1>Heading 3</h1>
```

Following is jquery selection code:

```
  $('h1');
```

Instead of returning Jquery Object it is returning

```
 <h1>Heading 1</h1>
```

Comment: Will  `$("h1");` work?

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni That’s exactly the same.

Comment: Oh ..me too just a beginner with javascript. :)

Comment: Please show how you have included jQuery and how you are executing this code.

Comment: i am executing it from console

Comment: Is it done like this?   `$(document).ready(function(){ $h1= $('h1');  });`

Comment: @NishantSrivastava Modern consoles have their own `$` function. How have you included jQuery?

Comment: @Xufox Thanks. jQuery was not getting loaded.

Answer (score -1):

using this selector : 
$('h1'); 
you should get access to a collection of items that matches the h1 tag specified.  In this case a collection with a length of 3.